# Generate all tuples with C - better way than nested loops?

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

I have an array `double x[]` of length 11 and a function `f(double x[])`. I want to find the minimum of the function `f()` by discretization. So for given values `val1, val2, ..., valn` I need a loop trough all the tuples of x in {val_1, ..., val_n}^11. I could easily use 11 nested loops, but is this really the most efficient I could do?

**Edit:**
To clarify things: the function f() is defined on an 11 dimensional set. I want to evaluate the function on the vertices of the an 11 dimensional grid. For a grid size `h`, possible values for the entries of the array `x[]` could be `0`, `h`, `2*h`, ..., `n*h` = val_1, val_2, ...,val_n . So in the beginning `f(val_1, val_1, ..., val_1)` should be evaluated, then `f(val_1, val_1, ...,val_1, val_2)`, ... and in the and  `f(val_n, val_n, ..., val_n)`. I don't care about the order actually, but I do care about speed, because there are many such tuples. To be precise, there are n^11 such tuples. So for n=10 `f()` has to evaluated 10^11 times. My computer can evaluate `f()` approximately 5*10^6 times per second, so for n=10 the evaluation of `f()`  takes 5 hours. That's why I'm searching for the most efficient way to implement it.

Comment: Do you really mean "efficient", or do you mean "neatest"?

Comment: I need something *really* fast. I expect the program to run many hours. But of course, if the code is *also* readable and flexible, it would be great.

Comment: What is f()? Can you find the minimum with pen and paper? Have you looked into gradient descent algorithms?

Comment: @Phonon Gradient descent finds a local minimum. I need a global one.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want to do...

Comment: @Ismael sorry, I hope I've clarified things now a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is pseudocode (not necessarily syntactically-correct C code) for a non-recursive approach to iterate over all possible tuples:

```
const int vals[]        = { val1, val2, val3, ... };

int       x[NUM_DIMS]   = { vals[0], vals[0], ... };  // The current tuple
int       i[NUM_DIMS]   = { 0 };                      // Index of each element in x[]


while (1)
{
    f(x);  // Whatever

    // Update x (we increment i[] treated as a base-N number)
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_DIMS; j++)
    {
        i[j]++;                          // Increment the current digit
        x[j] = vals[i[j]];               // Update (via mapping)
        if (i[j] < NUM_VALS) { break; }  // Has this digit wrapped?
        // We've caused a carry to the next digit position
        i[j] = 0;                        // Wrap
        x[j] = vals[0];                  // Update (via mapping)
    }
    if (j == NUM_DIMS) { break; }  // All digits wrapped, therefore game over
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth **Very** nice! That is definitely one of these implementations that needs *heavy* commenting (as evidenced by the number of comments to your answer).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: to be fair, the comments above were because I had failed to read the question properly.  But I will add comments.

Comment: Very nice, I agree. Please tell me you did not invent this on your own ;-)

Comment: @undur_gongor: I did, but I'm sure I'm not the first!  Once you realise that it can be expressed as a base-N integer, the implementation becomes obvious.

Comment: ... and with the comments that relation becomes clear. Really nice.

Answer (score 3):

The thing to do when the number of loops that you need is too high or is not known at compile time is to use recursion.

```
void check(double *x, int count) {
     // Check the tuple
}
void process(double *x, double *tuple, int count, int pos) {
    if (pos == count) {
        check(tuple, count);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0 ; i != count ; i++) {
            tuple[pos] = x[i];
            process(x, tuple, count, pos+1);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    double x[11] = {1,2,3...}, tuple[11];
    process(x, tuple, 11, 0);        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that sounds good. But isn't recursion quite slow compared to a for loop?

Comment: It is definitely slower than nested loops, yet it is *usually* not the recursion as an implementation technique that slows things down, but what you do on each level of the recursive invocation. In this case, I suspect the timing will be dominated by the speed of the `check` function.

Comment: Ah this is also a very useful hint! Unfortunately I'm sure that I won't be ably to optimize the function `check`.

Comment: @lumbric: If your `f` is slow, highly optimized generation of the tuples won't help much. You will spend most of the time in the 11^11 calls of `f` regardless of the algorithm for tuple-generation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reduce pressure on the processor cache. So perhaps if `N` in `val_N` is small, and you represent it by `N` instead of `N*h` as @OliCharlesworth suggests, you may be able to use a smaller type (e.g. `unsigned char`).

Also, the loop could be reduced to:

```
static inline int incx(uint8_t *x, unsigned int len) {
    ++*x;

    // compute any overflow
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (x[i] >= len && i < len) {
        x[i++] -= len;
        ++x[i];
    }

    // if the last value overflows, we're done
    return (i < len);
}

uint8_t x[LEN];

memset(x, 0, sizeof(x));

while (incx(x, sizeof(x)))
    f(x);
```